# Quarkus Camel Rest Route throwing a 401 Exception

Tags: java, exception, http-headers, apache-camel, quarkus

I have a rest route which when I don't add `Authorization` with the `Bearer` prefix in header works fine but once I add the `Bearer` to the prefix of the jwt, it fails.

I have written a custome authenticator to parse the passed jwt but when the right prefix is passed, it always fails with 401 exception.

Route

```
 restConfiguration().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);
 rest()
                .post("/sendBasicEmail")
                .route()
                .routeId("sendEmail")
                .process("authenticator") // does token verification
                .to("direct:processNotificationRequest")
                .endRest();
```

I am using `quarkus-camel 2.3.0` which internally uses `camel 3.11.2`

Any help will be appreciated.

Update - Process Authenticator code:

```
@Named("authenticator")
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
@ApplicationScoped
@Slf4j
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ServiceAuthenticator implements Processor {

    private final DefaultJWTParser parser;

    @Override
    public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String authorization = exchange.getMessage().getHeader("Authorization", String.class);

        JsonWebToken token;
        boolean isValidToken = true;
        try {
            log.info("incoming token {}", authorization);
            log.info("chunked incoming token {}", authorization.trim().substring(7));
            token = parser.parse(authorization.substring(7).trim()); // remove Bearer portion of the authorization header

            log.error("token parsed: {}", token);

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= token.getExpirationTime() || !token.getGroups().contains("USER")) {
                isValidToken = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception parsing token: {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            isValidToken = false;
        }
        if (!isValidToken) {
            throw new CoreException("JWT101", "Invalid or expired token");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must share authenticator processor

Comment: Whenever the Bearer prefix is added to the Authorization header,  the processor never get called, it just fails with 401 but without the Bearer prefix the processor is called.